# "Повседневный обиход" — плеоназм?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость, плеоназм

Обиход — повседневный уклад. "Повседневный обиход" — плеоназм, по-моему. Однако встречается часто, в Нацкорпусе я обнаружил 31 вхождение, есть и в словаре Кузнецова (см. ниже). Как это объяснить?

> [ОБИХОД](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%EE%E1%E8%F5%EE%E4), -а; м. 1. **Повседневный**, привычный уклад, образ жизни. В его обиходе ничего не изменилось. Домашний о. **Повседневный о.** // Употребление, пользование в повседневной жизни, в быту. Войти в о. (начать употребляться). Выйти, исчезнуть из обихода (перестать употребляться). В твоём обиходе есть такое слово? (ты употребляешь такое слово?). Предметы домашнего обихода (домашняя утварь). 2. Разг. Предметы хозяйства, быта, домашняя обстановка. Старый крестьянский о.: дровни, бороны, телеги. Небогатый у тебя о. 3. Церк. Правила церковного пения. Учитель обихода. // Название церковной нотной книги. Твёрдо знал весь о.

Comment: 31 вхождение – это часто?!

Comment: М_Г, в приведённой Вами словарной статье у слова _обиход_ есть ведь и второе значение: _" 2. Разг. Предметы хозяйства, быта, домашняя обстановка"._

Comment: @slava1947, жаль,что Вы не развили эту мысль. Вы хотите сказать, что применительно к предметам хозяйства можно говорить "повседневный обиход”? Спорно. О предметах  пишут "предметы повседневного обихода", но  здесь или первая или вторая пара плеонастична. Хорошо было бы получить от Вас полный ответ, а не комментарий.

Comment: @Niemand 31 вхождение — достаточно, чтобы заставить меня сомневаться в своей правоте и обратиться к другим за советом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Однако встречается часто, в Нацкорпусе я обнаружил 31 вхождение. Как
>   это объяснить?

Это выражение также можно встретить в толковых словарях (не только в приведенной в вопросе статье из Кузнецова, но и в словаре Дмитриева). Поэтому следует предположить самое простое объяснение: это устойчивое выражение.